# jQuery date/time picker and fullcalendar.io

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, time, slot

I bet I am over complicating things trying to use full calendar for something it is really not good at.

Here is the layout I would like to get.

[image: date time layout]

The issue I am having is fullcalendar.io is not this, its not a simple see the date above that you want and click a time that suits.

The user does not need to click the date just the time.

Comment: Please post the relevant code you've written so far.

Comment: thats the part that I am stuck, I have NO idea how fullcalendar could even be themed this way

Comment: @RussellHarrower hey! did you ever figure it out? Looking to do the same hting